# UNIX, change the interpreter line in all shell scripts

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, ksh

Can someone please tell me how to find out the pathname of the KornShell (ksh) on my machine and then change the interpreter line in all shell scripts (.sh) in the current directory that show a different pathname for ksh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will give you the path to Korn shell:

```
which ksh
```

And this will replace shebang in all shell scripts:

```
sed -i 's/#!\/bin\/bash/#!insert escaped ksh path here/' *.sh
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that he needs to escape the string that he inserts. Better yet, I suppose it's better to use something like: `echo 1/23|sed 's^/^2^'`. Also, you don't need `/g`, as it's hopefully only one per line... :)

Answer (score 3):

Put this in the first line of each file (shebang line):

`#!/usr/bin/env ksh`

If you need to replace you can use sed/awk: 
`find -name '*.sh' | xargs perl -pi -e "s{^#!/usr/bin/sh}{#!/usr/bin/env ksh}"`

Comment: Removed it. It was from a snippit I found which looked for .pl AND .cgi files. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Mine needed single quotes: `find -name '*.pl' | xargs perl -pi -e 's{^#!/usr/bin/perl}{#!/usr/bin/env perl}'`

Answer (score 3):

To find out where ksh lives:

```
whence -a ksh
```

To change all shell scripts in the current directory to use ksh:

```
sed -i '1{/^#!\/[^ ]*\/\(ba\|\)sh\( *\)/s||#!/bin/ksh\2|}' *.sh
```

This will match for `sh` or `bash` and preserve any spaces (and arguments) that appear afterwards. It only acts on the first line so it won't touch similar lines that may appear later in the file.

Substitute the actual location of your ksh executable or use `/usr/bin/env ksh`.

Use `sed -i .bak` if you want to backup the changed files.

Answer (score 0):

This command will locate the korn shell executable in your UNIX environment:

```
which ksh
```

If no output is returned, then the korn shell is missing. (At least not found in your environment PATH.) You can get it from the [KornShell](http://www.kornshell.com/) site or install it via your software package manager system.

In order to replace the interpreter line in all shell scripts (*.sh), you could run something like this:

```
sed -i "s/^#\!.*$/#\!\/bin\/ksh/" *.sh
```

The `-i` option is to edit files in place. (Warning: Test this command without the `-i` first, to avoid file modifications.)

The quoted argument is the pattern to match all lines starting with "#!" and replace them with "#!/bin/ksh". (Note that some special characters need to be escaped with "\" before.) You may need to customize this argument if it isn't exactly the replacement you're looking for.

Comment: Somehow I get an error: Illegal variable name. But this works:
`sed -i 's/^#\!.*$/#!\/bin\/ksh/' *.sh`

Answer (score 0):

On my machine only this works
`sed -i  "s/^#\!.*/#\!\/usr\/bin\/perl/" *.sh`
Everyother throws an error.